Non-simplicity of groups of order 1224
There is no simple group of order $1224 = 8 \times 9 \times 17$.
Ling and Miller gave a short proof in 1900. (G.H. Ling and G.A. Miller, "Proof that there is no Simple Group whose Order lies between 1092 and 2001", American Journal of Mathematics, vol. 22, No. 1, Jan., 1900, pp. 13-26, entirely available on JSTOR.)
Here is their proof :
"$1224 = 2^{3}.3^{2}.17.$
Since every group of this order contains 1 or 18 subgroups of order 17, a simple group of this order could be represented as a doubly-transitive group of degree 18. The maximal subgroup of degree 17 [= fixing a point] would be of order 68. The group of order 1224 would, therefore, contain a subgroup of order 8 that contains a substitution [= permutation] formed by four cycles of order 4 and substitutions of degree 18. Since the latter would have to be negative [= odd], the simple group is impossible. It might
appear that the group of order 8 could contain 5 substitutions of order 2 and degree 16, but this is impossible, since there would be just 17.9 conjugate substitutions of this kind."
I don't understand this proof. OK for the double transitivity, for the fact that such a group $G$ should have $18$ Sylow $17$-subgroups, that the normalizer of such a Sylow subgroup should be of order $68$ (and could not contain elements of order $34$), that there should be elements of order $4$ such that the cycle structure of the corresponding permutation of $Syl_{17}(G)$ should be 4-4-4-4-1-1, but what thereafter ? I have another proof, but it is long and I would like to understand Ling and Miller's one. Could anybody write it in a more explicit form ? Thanks in advance.
Edit 1. Below, Dietrich Burde copied an answer that David A. Craven had given on the deleted page. 21 hours ago, I made on the present page an objection to this proof , but since it is lost in the comments, I repeat it here. David A. Craven said :
"If $y\in G$ is an element of order a power of $2$ that does not fix two points, because it lies outside any point stabilizer (they must exist, for example by extending a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$ to one of $G$)"
I said that I was not sure that I understood this : "they must exist, for example by extending a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$ to one of $G$". I added : "Let $K$ be a Sylow $2$-subroup of $H$ and $D$ a Sylow $2$-subroup of $G$ containing $K$. Is it straightforward that an element of $D \setminus K$ cannot fix some other point ? "
Since David A. Craven didn't answer and Dietrich Burde and Steve D said that his proof is "fine", "absolutely fine", perhaps  Dietrich Burde and Steve D could help ? Thanks in advance.
Edit 2. Thanks to Derek Holt for his explanation.

You have asked this already last month, I think. And the comments said, that it takes a long time to write all details, but finally someone did. Where is this post? Ah, here it is. Why did you delete it? It is better to edit a post.

I didn't delete this post, I don't know why it was deleted. It seems that a page can be deleted if someone was rude on it. If anybody was rude, it was not me.

Then you should copy the answers you have obtained, also from the comments, and then ask about the remaining questions. Right now it is just a copy of your old post.

Why should I have copied David's answer, since it was not up to par? To humiliate him?

His proof is fine! And he did edit it, indeed (I checked it right now).

OK, he corrected his proof, I see it now on the deleted page. I had waited some hours and when I looked again for the page, it was deleted. Someone suggested restoring the old page. If that is done, this new page might be deleted.

I have to apologise to you. Your post was indeed deleted by other people. But  reposting the question then is still not the best option, because the work of the people who gave you an answer then is lost. You have to add then also all the answers to your post, or change the question accordingly.

@Dietrich Burde : Don't apologize, there is no problem, But why was the post deleted, in the first place ?

Dietrich Burde, you said : "the comments said, that it takes a long time to write all details, but finally someone did." No, it was not said that it takes a long time to write all details, it was said that my own proof, that I had posted, was too long to read and that I should pay those would take the trouble to read it.

Well, and also to validate and improve your long post. It said: You post a wall of text, and are essentially asking people to read your (by your own admission long) proof, validate it, and then improve it in some way....

On re-reading it, I think the proof in the answer could benefit from further elucidation.
Why can we not have a Sylow $2$-subgroup such as
$$\langle ((3, 4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 9, 10)(11, 12, 13, 14)(15, 16, 17, 18)
,\\ (1, 2)(4, 6)(7, 8)(9, 10)(11, 18)(12, 17)(13, 16)(14, 15) \rangle?$$
This is dihedral of order $8$ and contained in $A_{18}$.
This is the situation described by G. A. Miller when he says "It might appear that the group of order 8 could contain 5 substitutions of order 2 and degree 16 ...", and he goes on to say "but this is impossible, since there would be just 17.9 conjugate substitutions of this kind".
That final remark is perhaps a bit obscure. There are certainly $17.9=153$ two-point stabilizers, and hence this number of involutions fixing two points, and there are also $17.9$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, again one for each pair of points.
In the situation we are trying to rule out, where all involutions fix 2 points, and hence are all conjugate in $G$, each Sylow $2$-subgroup contains exactly $5$ involutions, but each involution fixes nine $2$-element sets and is hence contained in exactly $9$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, so we have $5 \times 17 \times 9/9$ involutions altogether, a contradiction.
Note that in the simple group ${\rm PSL}(2,17)$ of order $16\times 9 \times 17$, the Sylow $2$-subgroups are dihedral of order $16$ and so contain $9$ involutions each, and everything works out fine.

Thanks, Derek Holt. I will read that tomorrow.

Another mistake in the original answer is that the normalizer of a 17-cycle has order 8.17 in $A_{17}$. This is easily fixed since the complement is cyclic, though, and so it has a unique subgroup of order 68.

Here is David's answer, from the same question you have posted earlier, which was deleted:
Their proof is as follows. Since $|Syl_{17}(G)|=18$, $G$ embeds transitively in the alternating group of degree $18$, and the stabilizer $H$ of a point has order $68$. This group has order $4\cdot 17$ and lies in $A_{17}$, so contains a $17$-cycle. Since the centralizer of a $17$-cycle $x$ in $S_{17}$ is simply $\langle x\rangle$, and the normalizer in $A_{17}$ has order exactly $68$, we have identified $H$. We can now read off the cycle types of the elements of $H$: we have elements of order $4$ of cycle type $4^4,1^2$ (in $S_{18}$) and elements of order $2$ with cycle type $2^8,1^2$.
If $y\in G$ is an element of order a power of $2$ that does not fix two points, because it lies outside any point stabilizer (they must exist, for example by extending a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$ to one of $G$), then $y$ squares to an element of $H$, and its fixed-point-free. If it squares to $1$ it has cycle type $2^9$, if $y^2$ has order $2$ then $y$ must have cycle type $4^4,2$, and if $y^2$ has order $4$ then $y$ must have cycle type $8^2,2$. All of these are odd, a contradiction.

No, I didn't delete David's answer, but Derek Holt made a remark about his proof and then I posted this comment : "So Derek Holt is not satisfied with the proof of David A. Craven as it is. David A. Craven, may I ask if you agree with Derek Holt's remark ? If it is the case, perhaps you could correct your answer ? Thanks in advance." David didn't edit his proof.

@Panurge No, you are not right. David edited his proof and put in "a power of $2$", as Derek had said. I can still verify this, because the post is not deleted for me. So his proof is fine. No need, to downvote his proof.

FWIW this proof is absolutely fine. Not sure why the last question was deleted (I can't see any of these links), but I think it should be undeleted, because David deserves credit for his answer.

In David's proof, I'm not sure that I understand this : "they must exist, for example by extending a Sylow 2-subgroup of $H$ to one of $G$". Let $K$ be a Sylow $2$-subroup of $H$ and $D$ a Sylow $2$-subroup of $G$ containing $K$. Is it straightforward that an element of $D \setminus K$ cannot fix some other point ?
